# How to allow remote access to my database?

Tags: php, networking, odbc, dns

I am currently accessing the database by `$_SESSION['connection'] = odbc_connect('Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mysql;Option=3;', 'root', '');`

Apart fromt the fact that I need to get a password put on that account (and maybe even use another account than root? And probably change the databse name?), I want to write some code which I can disrtribute to be installed at several sites.

I want to use the same code at each site, although I can't know the IP addresses in advance. How do I go about that? Do I just tell their IT guy to set a DNS trandlation for something like `myDatabaseServer` and then substitue `Server=localhost` by `Server=myDatabaseServer` in the odbc_connect() call?  Or do I need to do somehing with the ODBC manager in the Windows control panel?

Hmmm, I should probably obfuscate or comple the code before ditributing it...

---

Update: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713429/remote-mysql-access) which said

```
In your MySQL configuration file (my.cnf), you need the following at least:
port         = 3306          # Port MySQL listens on 
bind-address = 192.168.1.15  # IP address of your server 
# skip-networking            # This should be commented out to enable networking
```

I presume that`bind-address` coudl be `myDatabaseServer`, so that I don't need to edit the config file for each remote site(?)

It also said `GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.15' IDENTIFIED BY '';` So that is a command that has to be run once on the databse?  But I can't know the IP adress in advance? In fact, multiple users may need access - can I wildcard it to 192.168.*.*?  Is thus really, really needed? Is there any way that I can dconfigure it once, not knowing in advance which range of netwrok addresses each user will use (I know that it sounds insecure, but could I just grant access to everyone and rely on password protection, plus no outsiders knowing that the databse is there?)

Comment: "maybe even use another account than root?" - cute... yes, lock that down.

Comment: Never connect to database as `root` from any application, or never allow connecting as `root` from any host (other than `localhost`) for a production level database; instead create another user.

Comment: +1 to  both. Yes, I know ... I was just using root for development. Don't worry, I will lock that down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bind-address` can only be set to an IP address, not a domain name, and refers to the outgoing IP address that the mysql server will bind to.

However, when connecting externally, you can always just set the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0` that way the mysql server will accept incoming 3306 connections on any interface it has access to. The admin side would look after naming the server, and you can connect to it by that name.

Once that is set correctly you just need the appropriate user credentials set up, so that an external user can connect from a given IP (or pattern).

e.g.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO USERNAME@IP IDENTIFIED BY "PASSWORD";
```

[See here](http://help.hardhathosting.com/question.php/87#examples) for external IP patterns.

Of course, you should use a limited access account in general, and allow access to only specific database/tables (db.* is usually acceptable)

Comment: this helped me and it wasn't my question!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Slomojo's accurate answer:  Don't forget to `flush privileges;` in mysql after making any changes to privileges.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the *Post answer* button only if you have an answer of your own. If you want to correct another answer, use the "edit" link on that answer to edit it.

Comment: I looked for a way to do that.  Maybe I'm not allowed yet because my reputation is low as a new member.  The "Add Comment" appears on this post, but not on any other.  The Edit does - but when I click it it appears to allow me to modify the message itself, not tack a comment underneath (with a note saying any such change will first be reviewed).  I really want to get this right - Stack Overflow is such a tremendous resource and I have just now started contributing...

Comment: That's what the intent is, to modify the answer, which you can do even if you are a new member, not to add a new comment to it, which you can do once you reach 50 reputation points.  Once you modify the answer, other users with reviewing privileges can review the edit and possibly accept it.