# Unable to remotely connect MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, vpn

I am having two machines one located in India and other in USA. I want to access the Database of USA having following details:

```
username: root
IP-address of VPN: 192.168.91.201
IP-address(Global): 10.21.19.6
password: root1
```

Now in India I want to connect to this database but the problem the MySql installed in US machine is not properly configured to have connections remotely.

I want to configure it to work properly. I have access to US machine so I can perform configurations using remote login.

Comment: This is not a real question! Please detail your exact issue more carefully.

Comment: could you show the error you get when you try to connect.

Comment: have you seen this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: yes I already went through the above link.The problem is when I have also edited the /etc/myysql/my.cnf but it is not working for me.The problem is Mysql is by default not set to have connections from the remote clients and even when I am trying to configure it,it is not connecting.The error is java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '10.21.19.6' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713429/remote-mysql-access

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you simply need to add a new user for the remote ip allocated by your VPN and database you wish to connect to.

```
GRANT ALL ON yourdatabase.* TO anewuser@'ip.allocated.by.vpn' IDENTIFIED BY 'NEW_PASSWORD';
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin,Please also tell me that ,I have to run this query on the local database or remote database?Please clear the meaning of " and "iplocatedbyVPN" beacuse when I am running it on local system I am getting this error:ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'doqeap'

Comment: I'm assuming (probably incorrectly) you are connecting to the remote database, via a vpn, and this is allocating an ip to you local machine. You need to permission the user/ip/database on the database you wish to log on to. (the error mesage should really be posted in your question)