# Which IP to connect into a localNetwork?

Tags: mysql

I have two computers. Computer A and computer B. A have got a MySQL server and B has got a program, which will eventualy connect into computer B to get information from the database.
Both computers use the same Wifi.

Now the question is: Which IP should I use? I have tried the real IP, which is something like: 189.xxx.xxx.xxx and the IPV4 IP, which is something like 192.168.xx.xxx.

Sadly, none of them seem to work. My code is working in a localhost, but thats not what I want. Here is the following. Which string should I use for conIP?

```
 string conIP = "" //What should I use here?
 string conUser = "XXX";
 string conPass = "XXXXX";
 string conDB = "teste_etb";
 cs = ("Persist Security Info=False;server='" + conIP + "';database= '" + conDB + "' ;uid= '"+conUser + "';pwd='" + conPass + "' ");
```

I have already tried both of the methods, with no sucess. Please, if there is anything that might help, reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely the MySQL server on A is not listening to anything else then localhost (as that is by default the case for security reasons).  Maybe this SO answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713429/remote-mysql-access
Otherwise it could be also possible that your wifi is blocking access to other devices in the network, try pinging machine A from B.

Comment: I can't find my.ini (my.cnf in linux). I have alread looked in every possible post. Here is an old post just saying that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502433/find-my-ini-file-on-windows-7

Comment: Second thing: If I use computer B, it always connect to localhost, even thou I'm not typing localhost in any part of the code. When using another computer, it just crashes.

Comment: Use the 192.xxx.xxx.xxx or check the IP address again